# How to stop important emails in Gmail from going into Trash?

Tags: gmail

Right now, I am in a big problem with Gmail and I really need someone to help me.
All my important emails are going directly into the trash without my notice. Let me tell you with an example.

I receive newsletters daily from `info@*****.com`. All these newsletters used to appear in either *Primary* or *Promotions* tabs.

But, now they are directly appearing in *Trash* without my notice. Before this started happening, I created an account in `www.otherinbox.com` to unsubscribe from some newsletters. And from the very next day, this Trash problem started happening.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 3):

It sure sounds like the `otherinbox` service is doing this. If you revoke `otherinbox`'s access to your inbox, the problem should go away:

1. Go to https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1
2. Find `otherinbox` on the list, and click on it
3. From the right-hand sidebar, click *Revoke access*

If you cannot find `otherinbox` in the list, you must have given it access to your inbox some other way (perhaps by giving them your Gmail password?). In that case, change your Gmail password to lock out `otherinbox`.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit for me was [Unroll.me](https://unroll.me/). I'd used that service to opt out of certain emails, and when I wanted a certain organization's email again, I'd forgotten that I was using Unroll.me.

It's still a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

If you had ever used any tool like unroll.me, you have to go to your Gmail settings>Forwarding and POP/IMAP.
There you have to disable POP and IMAP.
Your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me about two years ago.  After exhausting all other possibilities, I deleted ALL of the filters I had created to keep stubborn spam from appearing in any mailbox.  Previously, those filters worked just fine until the one day when my messages began redirecting to Trash. That procedure cured the problem.

Several months later, I very carefully created a small number of filters (3 or 4) to weed out some new repetitive spam that annoying me.  Immediately, much important email starting ending up in Trash, as before.  Reluctantly, I deleted the simple filters and, voila, Gmail was performing correctly again.

It was a simple but hard-to-discover fix for me, and it may work for you.

Of course, the false redirection is the symptom of a deeper defect within the Gmail system, one that Google techies are either unable or unwilling to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Otherinbox doesn't work for Gmail users anymore so you can try something else instead. I was using Unroll.me before they were caught on privacy issue with selling user data, now I am using [Clean Email](http://clean.email), same functionality, you can set up rules for important emails and they will never come to Trash

Answer (score -1):

Please check your settings: Go to *filters*, check if any email address is there in matches and change the action related to it, *eg:- do this:- delete*

Answer (score -2):

Create a filter for this address:

1. Tick on a message from info@whatever.com
2. Go to More > Create filter
3. Tick your desired options (I'd go with "never send it to Spam" + "always mark it as important" )
4. Create filter ticking "also apply filter to matching conversations"

Maybe step 3 would require more effort, as applying a label, but first try this way.

Comment: The OP mentions "Trash", not "Spam".

Comment: whooops. my bad. should i remove the answer?